# UnknownFormatConversionException. What is the issue here?

Tags: java

I am copying code directly out of the book and it doesn't work. I can't figure out what the error is.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
double depositAmount;
System.out.print("Enter deposit amount for account1: ");
depositAmount = input.nextDouble();
System.out.printf("\nadding %.2f to account1 balance\n\n", depositAmount);
account1.credit(depositAmount);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
run:
account1 balance: $50.00
account2 balance: $0.00

Enter deposit amount for account1: 25.50

adding $25.50 to account1 balance

Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '.'
at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2547)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2533)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2469)
at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
at account.Account.main(Account.java:50)

Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Comment: What is line 50?
at account.Account.main(Account.java:50) keep reading, does the book want you to run into the mistake to transition into the next lesson?

Comment: Are you entering a `$` as input and trying to convert it to a double?

Comment: The code and output don't seem to line up. Where is this in your code: "account1 balance: $50.00 account2 balance: $0.00"? Also if you could point out which line is 50 that'd be useful. Chances are you have a format specifier in your `printf` that's incorrect in some way, but hard to tell with the code you posted.

Comment: can you please post the `account1.credit` body function?

Comment: Found the issue. Thanks guys. How did you know the problem was line 50?

Comment: By reading your stack trace `at account.Account.main(Account.java:50)`

Comment: @Math Thanks man, that's something I didn't know.